# Lost identification documents and don’t know what to do

Tags: passports, nigerian-citizens

So I’m 19 and I have no identification at all I’m from Nigeria but I came over to the U.K. when I was 5 and lived here since I had a leave to remain and a biometrics card but lost that so literally I have no ID at all I’ve tried all different ways to get something but I can’t find any solutions I just need some advice and where to go because I have no passport or no birth certificate.

Comment: Have you tried the Nigerian embassy?

Comment: Do you or your parents have any electronic records of being granted the leave to remain, other visas, etc?

Comment: When did you lose your BRP? You need to report its loss in order to get a replacement https://www.gov.uk/biometric-residence-permits/lost-stolen-damaged

Comment: This might be better on Expats.

Comment: @Traveller True enough, but even to order a replacement BRP will undoubtedly require a passport, so the OP should start with the Nigerian embassy.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica True enough, however the OP may be liable for a fine of up to £1,000 and/or made to leave the UK if they do not apply for a replacement BRP/BRC within 3 months, so they should not delay contacting Immigration

Comment: @Traveller If the BRC was lost more than 3 months ago, then the OP risks being ordered to leave the UK, and should obtain some local (in-the-UK) professional advice _before_ contacting Immigration.